# Async Socket receiving data in the wrong order or missing

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets

I've asked about this topic before and thought I had a handle on it but I'm finding I'm missing something here.  I've got some C code in linux that I'm sending data through a socket to my C# winforms visualization code.  I'm sending the data from C as fast as I can calculate it which pretty damn fast.  But in C# my datagridview is not updating correctly.  If I slow down the rate at which I am sending the data to the c# code it does okay.  But I can't really do that.    I really am dying here.

So in C# this is what I have:

```
{
   . . .
sListener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
sListener.Bind(new IPEndPoint(0, 1994));
Listen();
}
private void Listen()
    {
        sListener.Listen(10);

        // Begins an asynchronous operation to accept an attempt 
        AsyncCallback aCallback = new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback);
        sListener.BeginAccept(aCallback, sListener);
    }

    public void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Socket listener = null;

        // A new Socket to handle remote host communication 
        Socket handler = null;
        try
        {
            // Receiving byte array 
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            // Get Listening Socket object 
            listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            // Create a new socket 
            handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

            // Using the Nagle algorithm 
            handler.NoDelay = false;

            // Creates one object array for passing data 
            object[] obj = new object[2];
            obj[0] = buffer;
            obj[1] = handler;

            // Begins to asynchronously receive data 
            handler.BeginReceive( buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None,  new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), obj);

            // Begins an asynchronous operation to accept an attempt 
            AsyncCallback aCallback = new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback);
            listener.BeginAccept(aCallback, listener);
        }
        catch (Exception exc) { MessageBox.Show(exc.ToString()); }
    }

    public void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Fetch a user-defined object that contains information 
            object[] obj = new object[2];
            obj = (object[])ar.AsyncState;

            // Received byte array 
            byte[] buffer = (byte[])obj[0];

            // A Socket to handle remote host communication. 
            handler = (Socket)obj[1];

            // Received message 
            string content = string.Empty;

            // The number of bytes received. 
            int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                Array.Resize(ref buffer, bytesRead);
                double[] values = new double[buffer.Length / 8];
                int i = 0;
                values[i] = BitConverter.ToDouble(buffer, i * 8);
                values[++i] = BitConverter.ToDouble(buffer, i * 8);
                values[++i] = BitConverter.ToDouble(buffer, i * 8);
                values[++i] = BitConverter.ToDouble(buffer, i * 8);
                values[++i] = BitConverter.ToDouble(buffer, i * 8);

                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
                {
                    if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 5)
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(this.dataGridView1.Rows[5].Index);
                    }
                    dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = values[0];
                    dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[1].Value = values[1];
                    dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[1].Value = values[2];
                    dataGridView1.Rows[3].Cells[1].Value = values[3];
                    dataGridView1.Rows[4].Cells[1].Value = values[4];

                });
            }
            // Continues to asynchronously receive data
            byte[] buffernew = new byte[1024];
            obj[0] = buffernew;
            obj[1] = handler;
            handler.BeginReceive(buffernew, 0, buffernew.Length,
            SocketFlags.None,
            new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), obj);                   
        }
        catch (Exception exc) { MessageBox.Show(exc.ToString()); }
    }
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Can you assign an ID or incremental value to the data received, and simply sort the data after that?

Comment: no, I will be sending data from C continuously

Comment: What about adding an (incremented) int to the object array you are passing to ReceiveCallback then?

Comment: that might help, but I think I'm missing some of the data as well.

Comment: Should I just give up on the asynchronous and do a synchronous socket?  from C I am just sending an array of 5 doubles every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your async code is firing async, which is as expected... But this means that the order of processing could differ from the order of receive. For example:

```
.NET receive message 1
.NET receive message 2
.NET finish receive message 2
.NET finish receive message 1
```

Here you assumed you'd see 1, then 2 since that's the order they were received in, but NOT the order they finished being received in.

If the order of your data is important, you must either send all of it at once in a large batch (bad), or receive it sequentially (the underlying TCP should ensure that messages are delivered in the appropriate order).

Comment: Okay so I rewrote my code using a non async socket and it seems to work fine.  However I send the data too fast so I can't process the data before the next set is trying to process it.  So now I am just processing it and sending a message back to the Linux app that says its okay to send me more data.  Is that bad?

Comment: It depends on your unique scenario. I'd probably try to open up the socket for listening ASAP, so once you receive, add the entry to a Queue<T> that is locked on properly and process from there, re-opening the socket for the next message... Then process your messages from the Queue on another thread. Something like that.